# How do i select rows where some fields are duplicated but other fields are compared in mySql

Tags: mysql

I have 1 table. 4 fields. How do I find the records that have duplicate values in `Species` AND they have duplicate values in `Location`, and `Foo` is compared to `Bar` in other records? (I'm looking for `Foo` less than `Bar`)

```
RecordId    Species   Location    Foo    Bar
1           Cat       home        4      9
2           Dog       home        4      9
3           Cat       home        3      7
4           Bunny     home        4      9
5           Cat       home        1      2
```

I want to find the records 1 and 3. Both have Cat (in `Species`) AND home (in `Location`) and `Foo` in record 1 is `4` which is less than `Bar` in record 3 (which is `7`). Record 5 doesn't match because `Foo` in Record 1 is not less than `Bar` in record 5.

If I have not worded the question properly please don't just close the it. I am happy to edit if need be.

Comment: What is expected result?

Comment: Yes it will have a primary key. I just didn't add it to keep it simple. 1st record id = 1, 2nd record id =2 etc. The expected result is to return the 2 records . record 1 and 3. ideally the id of both records.

Comment: *I want to find the records 1 and 3* why 5th was ignored it also matches your criteria ?

Comment: 5th doesnt match.Field 3 in record 1 is not less than field 4 in record 5. That is the the part that is tricky for me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down:

### Part 1: Records that share duplicate values in `Field1` and `Field2`:

This is straightforward enough. The query below returns all of the `(Species + Location)` tuples which appear more than once in the source table.

```
SELECT
    Species,
    Location
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Species,
    Location
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This gives these results:

```
Species   Location
Cat       home
```

Then we want to get the original raw records (non-grouped) that have these known-duplicate values, we do that by doing an `INNER JOIN` with this back on the original table:

```
SELECT
    table.*
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Species,
            Location
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            Species,
            Location
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS duplicates ON
        table.Species  = duplicates.Species AND
        table.Location = duplicates.Location
```

(It can be tempting to have it as a `WHERE` subquery, but that is much less flexible and a less "relational" way of thinking about the problem)

This then gives these results:

```
RecordId    Species   Location  Foo    Bar
1           Cat       home      4      9
3           Cat       home      3      7
5           Cat       home      1      2
```

### Part 2: Filter based on `Foo` and `Bar`:

This is more complicated... here's the rules you gave:

- Record 1: Included because the record's `Foo == 4` is less than Record 3's `Bar == 7`.
- Record 3: You don't explain why Record 3 is included besides it meeting the duplicate criteria - or why record 3's `Bar = 7` is used to compare with Record 1 when Record 1's `Bar = 9` is higher.
- Record 5: Excluded because the record 1's `Foo == 4` is greater than record 5's `Bar == 2`.

My interpretation is that inside each group (records 1, 3 and 5 in this case) only return records where `Bar > MAX( Foo )`. In this case, `MAX( Foo ) == 4`, so records 1 and 3 are included because `9 > 4` and `7 > 4` respectively, but 5 is not because `2 > 4` is false.

We'll take the groups from the earlier query and add a `MAX` aggregate:

```
SELECT
    Species,
    Location,
    MAX( Foo ) AS MaxFoo
FROM
    table
GROUP BY
    Species,
    Location
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

This gives these results:

```
Species   Location    MaxFoo
Cat       home        4
```

(Because this query is a superset of the original subquery we don't need to `JOIN` on a second query but we can edit it in-place):

```
SELECT
    table.*
FROM
    table
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            Species,
            Location,
            MAX( Foo ) AS MaxFoo
        FROM
            table
        GROUP BY
            Species,
            Location
        HAVING
            COUNT(*) > 1
    ) AS duplicates ON
        table.Species  = duplicates.Species AND
        table.Location = duplicates.Location
WHERE
    table.Bar > duplicates.MaxFoo
```

And this query gives you your desired results:

```
RecordId    Species   Location  Foo    Bar
1           Cat       home      4      9
3           Cat       home      3      7
```

This query also shows the advantage of `JOIN` operations on subqueries instead of `WHERE` subqueries because you can perform more operations on the data (e.g. if you wanted to include `MaxFoo` in the output then just change `SELECT table.* FROM...` to `SELECT table.*, duplicates.MaxFoo FROM...`).